# License considerations with Java 9 deprecations

Tags: licensing, java, cddl

I'm using the javax.activation package in a project that is deployed as a monolithic jar. The mentioned package is licensed under CDDL 1.0 and up to now part of the Java distribution but is now deprecated in Java 9 and will be removed from Standard Edition in later versions.

To be future-proof, I'm including the [standalone replacement project](https://github.com/javaee/activation#javabeans-activation-framework-jaf) as dependency in my projects Maven configuration and would include the compiled code in my jar as not to introduce an obstacle to the intended users.

The javax.activation package license was no problem until now, because my jar only linked to the code in the Java distribution.

If I'm not able to release the source of my application, what are my options?

- Include the external code in my jar file
- Bundle my jar with the dependencies jar and distribute both as a zip file
- Only distribute my jar and let the users cope with getting the right dependencies themselfes
- Force the users to stay with up to Java 8

Edit: The package version on Github actually uses CDDL 1.1, while on mvnrepository.com it's listed as CDDL 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CDDL 1.1 license does not require you to release your own source code.

To comply with the license, if you include the `javax.activation` package in your distribution, you should mention in your documentation that you are using the `javax.activation` package, which license that package is under and where people can obtain the source code.
You can just include the package in your monolithic jar file.

Only if you make changes to the `javax.activation` package itself or if you physically copy code from that package to other files are you requires to make source code public.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect that the package actually uses CDDL 1.1.

Comment: @user2011659: That doesn't materially change my answer, as I based it on the actual license text found with the package.